# How to make your website works on a projector?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a presentation tomorrow, and while I was trying to project my website using projector 
all the elements appeared mixed up. The problem is I used a software called "AXURE" to do the website. The HTML files produced by this software are crap. There's no one unified CSS file. The style is embedded for each element in the `<div>` tag and every element is positined by absolute pixels. How can make my website works on larger screens?

Comment: recode.. and don't use axure nexttime

Comment: Why would it look any different on the projector than on your screen?  If it looks crap on your screen it'll look like crap projected.  As for you CSS, best thing you can do is manually fix it.  And the quickest way to do so is utilizing find and replace in a text editor.

Comment: You mean your pages look like the sickies on a wall http://www.axure.com/ xD?

Comment: LOOOOOOOL i just noticed guys : Axure used " see it happen " as their moto XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. Inline style elements take precedence over the other stylesheet declarations. Especially if none of the elements have classes or id's in them. Possibly look up the documentation on AXURE to see if it provides a method for formatting to larger displays.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the resolution on the projector really small (like 800x600 or whatever AXURE used... Not a viable long-term solution, but good in a crunch like this